# Finding count of unique values based on hierarchical excel data

Tags: excel

I have an excel data set that is essentially a nested list, structured as so:

```
+------+------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Lvl1 | Lvl2 |   Lvl3       |     Lvl4       |   Lvl5    | Count |Weight |
+------+------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------+-------+
| X1   | X2   | X3           | B1             | N/A       |     2 | 6%    |
| X1   | X2   | X3           | B2             | C1        |     2 | 3%    |
| X1   | X2   | X3           | B2             | D1        |     2 | 3%    |
+------+------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

Each X variable has a weighting in a different column (not shown - lets call it W1-W5 with W3-W5 unknown), while the B-D variables don't. In the above example, X3 has a weighting of 12%. B1 and B2 would each have a weighting of 6%, but then B2 would be split in two for a weighting of 3% each.

THE GOAL: I need a column with each line calculating the count of variables (n) applied to the parent weight so I can then divide that n to the corresponding variable weight. 
THE ISSUE: Having varying levels of unknowns makes it difficult to check the parent/grandparent levels for headers that apply to the same weighting.

My current solution has been to find the count of X3, then applying that count of X3 to the range of Lvl4, seeing how many are unique in that range, then counting the range in Lvl5. My goal is to get the count of line items (to divide the weighting) for the lowest level and second lowest level

My formulas are becoming unwieldy, with no solution in sight. Thanks in advance!

My current solutions, that I don't know how to make dynamic across variables and columns. I have tried using offsets, using the range of the parent level, but this only works when there is one level between the known weighting and the unknown weighting.

```
To find number of X3's:
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(
IF($C$2:$C$4<>"",
MATCH($C$2:$C$14,$C$2:$C$4,0)),
ROW($C$C:$C$4)
-ROW($C$2)
+1),1))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output from your table provided

Comment: The expected output would be the count and weighting. Honestly the count is a helper column, going through this by hand, even if the count for B2 is 2, there would still need to be additional logic to tie that count to the weighting of X3. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: VBA is where you would start.
https://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html
It would be like programming your own functions but slightly easier.

Comment: If you want help with the VBA code (if there is any sensitive information) feel free to reach out on LinkedIn under my profile.

Comment: "each line calculating the count of variables (n) applied to the parent weight.." >> some example (value, input n output) please..